# Display public Google Photos album in Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm designing a flutter app where we have some 'public' Google Photos album URL added through some channels. All we have is the album URL and I would like to display those photos in Flutter app itself rather than displaying a link and letting the user browse the photos in Chrome or some browser. Any ideas on how do I do it? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use a third party tool for unintended purposes. Google "might" close Photos service so your app will become offline. Or it might change the exact part you're sending request to get images. Same thing will happen again. Anyways you can create a server that uses [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos) to fetch images (do not do this on the client side, otherwise you will expose api keys to the open internet!)

Comment: Hey @Angappan Ganesh, Did you find any suitable solution for that, other than using google photo api's?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use **WebView**: https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2

But more advanced is to build a repository and read data to it and display using **ListView Builder** or something like that. This may need implementing an interface API layer.

This tutor may help you: https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-display-anonymous-number-of-images-in-flutter-using-listview-builder-e2e8aaa2fa0a